# Angular-Wizard's nz-step with ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays

I have tried using **wz-step** with **ng-repeat**,

Example:

```
<wizard>
<wz-step>
" 'datatables' array is getting updated here"
</wz-step>
<wz-step ng-repeat="datatable in datatables">
"input fields based on values inside datatable"
</wz-step>
</wizard>
```

on page load it works as expected but when the array (eg: datatables) got updated then it keeps on appending new steps at the end (instead of replacing existing wz-steps with the new wz-steps as per new updated array).

Even array(datatables) is also getting updated as expected.

So, Is there any option to remove (reset) my existing steps, and replace it with updated array.

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance